# Numerals to ordinals in JabRef jstyle layout file

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, jabref

I have created a .jstyle layout file for JabRef (I am using JabRef version 2.11.1) for formatting citations for the journal, *Florida Entomologist* (FL_Ent). Although the current (25 March 2015) Manuscript Formatting Guidelines for FL_Ent fail to stipulate anything about how editions of a book should be formatted in their *References Cited* list, an earlier version of the formatting guidelines (28 July 2013) stated that the edition should be written as an ordinal followed by "edn." Therefore, the second edition of a book should be formatted, '*book title*, 2nd edn.' I would like to know how to convert numerals into their ordinal analogues in the context of JabRef .jstyle files. For example, I need to take the numeral "2" and convert it into "2nd". It seems that the `Replace` formatter could be useful in this, because it allows regex patterns to be searched for. However, I believe its actual replacement functionality is too restrictive to be applied in a general manner, in that it only replaces matched text with a static string, so that, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. would all have to be handled individually. Is there a way to use `Replace`, or some other JabRef formatter, so that one command would handle all ordinal replacements?

Here is an example of the use of the `Replace` formatter in a .jstyle layout file: "`\format[Replace(\s,_)]{\author}` : will output the "author" field after replacing all whitespace by underscores."

The class description for the Replace formatter reads: "Formatter that does regexp replacement. To use this formatter, a two-part argument must be given. The parts are separated by a comma. To indicate the comma character, use an escape sequence: \, ... The first part is the regular expression to search for. ... The second part is the text to replace all matches with." (http://api123.io/api/JabRef/head/net/sf/jabref/exporter/layout/format/Replace.html)

Comment: I am unsure whether this is doable. If you don't get help here the next days, please file an issue at [JabRef's issue tracker](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues).

Comment: BTW: The real user's help is at http://help.jabref.org/en/CustomExports/.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I missed this for a couple of days. I wasn't being notified of activity via email but thought that I was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once merged, there will be a formatter named Ordinal in the JabRef master branch... Then it should be just to write:

```
\format[Ordinal]
```

Comment: Would be better if you added more details such as what is being merged...

Comment: OK, I made a pull request to JabRef, https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/pull/830 that once merged in the master branch will provide the new requested formatter.

Comment: Has this already been merged? http://help.jabref.org/en/CustomExports/ already shows the Ordinal formatter. Will I need to upgrade to JabRef 3.x to be able to use it?

Comment: I upgraded to JabRef 3.2. Previously the connection between JabRef and LibreOffice had been broken in JabRef 3, but it's now operational again: https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/526 (I also needed to upgrade to Java 8.). I found the new Ordinal formatter was not available, however, so I downloaded JabRef-3.3dev and enjoyed the new functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there is such a functionality in general, but why not just repeat a couple of replacement functions? It's just a bit more (hidden) code:

```
\begin{edition} 
\format[Replace(1,1st),Replace(2,2nd),Replace(3,3rd)...]
{\edition}, \end{edition}
```

-> this should do it for you in almost every case.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  The poster specifically asked for something was not case-by-case.

Comment: While that's true, the solution proposed delivers a bibliography with correct references - without any case-by-case modifications needed.

Comment: Indeed.  Note however, it will fail on each addition after the tenth.  You need a more specific regular expressions, cf. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4707